# HTTPClient POST request not working on Angular 5 / Angular Universal

Tags: angular, mean-stack, crud, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I've been having trouble trying to implement a simple MEAN Stack CRUD application using a RESTful API as described in this article: [MEAN Stack (Angular 5) CRUD Web Application Example](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example).

I first created the app using Angular 5 only ([GitHub repo here](https://github.com/Stanza987/mean-crud-example)), and that worked great!  Then, I tried recreating the app using Angular 5 / Angular Universal, and that's when I started running into problems.  I can perform GET/DELETE requests without issues.  However, **I am unable to perform POST/PUT requests (I used a template-driven form using ngModel)**.

Essentially, after submitting the form, my `console.log` in node shows a **`GET request (status 304)`**, and the URL is `/book-create?title=&author=` which leads me to believe that my input fields are not even being recorded.  For what it's worth, all of my logged requests are `GET requests (status 304)`, even the web pages that load correctly.  I tested my back-end API with Postman and it works as expected.

I know Angular Universal does server-side rendering so

1. Is the reason my POST requests aren't working because the **view isn't being rendered in the client?**
2. Does the **304 status code** has something to do with this issue?

Relevant code snippets are shown below.  Thanks for the help!

**book-create.component.ts**

```
export class BookCreateComponent implements OnInit {

book: any = {};

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

saveBook() {
this.http.post('api/book', this.book)
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.router.navigate(['/books']);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}}
```

**book-create.component.html**

```
<form #bookForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveBook()">
  <input required name="title" [(ngModel)]="book.title" type="text">
  <input required name="author" [(ngModel)]="book.author" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

**server.js**

```
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node'); // COMMENT: Server specific version of Zone.js

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ngUniversal = require('@nguniversal/express-engine'); // COMMENT: SSR Engine
const appServer = require('./dist-server/main.bundle'); // COMMENT: Server Bundle

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const api = require('./routes/api');

const config = require('./config/database');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect(config.database, { useMongoClient: true, promiseLibrary: 
require('bluebird') })
  .then(() => console.log(`Connected to database ${config.database}`))
  .catch((err) => console.log(`Database error: ${err}`));

app.engine('html', ngUniversal.ngExpressEngine({ // COMMENT: Engine Config
  bootstrap: appServer.AppServerModuleNgFactory
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'dist');

function serverRouter(req, res, next) => {
  if (req.url.startsWith('/api')) return next();
  res.render('index', { req, res });
}

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', serverRouter); // COMMENT: Server-side rendering of root route
app.use('/api', api);
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/dist`));
app.get('*', serverRouter);

// API Error Handler here (not shown)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: When using angular universal, URLs passed to http client must be absolute

Comment: Noted, thanks! Unfortunately, changing to absolute URLs did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what was going on so I decided to delete the whole app and start from scratch by 1. cloning the original working project and then 2. using my Angular 5 w/ Angular Universal starter kit to integrate Angular Universal by recreating the changes made to the Angular source files manually that would have been done using `ng g universal universal`:

1. MEAN CRUD Example - https://github.com/Stanza987/mean-crud-example
2. MEAN Starter Kit w/ Angular Universal - https://github.com/Stanza987/mean-starter-kit

After doing that, I ran the app and it had no issues! ..?  I re-checked server.js and it was identical to the one I posted above, so I'm not sure what went wrong.  My HttpClient POST/PUT requests worked this time.  I wish I could say I found a solution, but I guess I'll never know.  I guess I'm confident now that `this.http.post('api/book', this.book)` will work with Angular Universal.

@David: thanks, I appreciate your help in thinking this through.

Comment: That is weird. I have the same issue: express goes unresponsive when angular tries to use HttpService. No response and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a proxy for sending the api requests to another server?
If so, is the error that you missed  a slash for "api/book" ? I think it should be

```
/api/book
```

Answer (score 1):

Use httpHeaders instead of Headers for POST and PUT

Comment: please, add some code example to make it easier to understand to the person who asked